# how to replace standard multiselect options with checkbox dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace standard `multiselect` options ( which we have to keep pressed command button and then select multiple options ) with checkbox dropdown (that when i check the item, all the checked items are displayed  in the header).

I have the following select options

```
    <select multiple="" class="multimenu">
     <option value="a">Playing</option>
     <option value="b">Singing</option>
     <option value="c">Listening</option>
     <option value="d">Sleeping</option>
     <option value="e">Chatting</option>
   </select>
```

Now i want to replace the above such that there is a checkbox with each item.. and all the checked item(s), when checked, are displayed in the header.

I just want to transform the functionality, interface just same as normal single select select options but the only difference is, there is a checkbox infront of each item,, and when i tick the checkbox, each of the ticked item(s) is displayed in the header.

How can i attempt the same..??

Comment: You might want to consider using the jquery multiselect plugin.

Comment: Do you want to replace the element dynamically with JS or are you asking for the HTML?

Comment: i want to replace the element dynamically with js. kindly read second last line for clear objective.

Comment: Ok, but why create a `select` box in the first place if you don't want to use it?

Comment: i must assume that `<select>` has an `id` or a `name`, right ?

Comment: yes you can have <select> id or class preferably..

Comment: @FelixKling i create select box just to show that i want the interface very close like a normal select dropdown. but only difference with a checkbox for each item in drop down.

Comment: @DerekHenderson NO, Jquery multiselect plugin is not suitable for me. I have checked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle your form data using a select box, but would prefer to display it to the user as a dropdown list with checkboxes for selecting each option, look no further than Dropdown Check List:

https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/